# Laravel Full calendar 5 - Clicking event takes me to URL/undefined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-5.6

My calendar loads just fine with all events. This is how I'm constructing it:

```
    $events = [];

    foreach($CalendarClasses as $Q){

        $events[] = Calendar::event(

            $Q->Classes->UserCourse->Course['code'],
            true,
            new \DateTime($Q->date),
            new \DateTime($Q->date)

        );
    }

    $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events);
```

Here's a sample event:

`"events":[{"id":null,"title":"CSC 422","allDay":true,"start":"2018-09-16T00:00:00+02:00"}]`

Whenever I click an event or attempt to trigger the eventPopover (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover), I get redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/undefined`

I tried to use a callback as in

```
$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)->setCallbacks([
            'eventClick' => 'function(event) {
             event.preventDefault(); }'
                ]);
```

But it's just not working. I don't need any eventClick events, I just want the popover to display and no events to be triggered when an event is clicked. What do I do?

I'm using `fullcalendar/2.2.7`.

Comment: "This UI component only applies to month view, basic view, and the “all-day” slot of agenda view"
did you consider this?

Comment: @Hussein Yes, I'm trying to display it in the "month" view. The number of events displayed per day is limited to the height of the element holding the day. The "+2 more" is supposed to trigger a popover with the remaining events, but instead it redirects me to /undefined. The popover is displayed correctly, it's just that I get redirected for no apparent reason.